# Making jQuery Code More Correct/ Efficient

Tags: jquery

Hey! I've finally started feeling comfortable using jQuery, so now I'm trying to improve the I write my code. Is there anyone who could help me make this code more efficient?

```
$("a.more_info").toggle(function(){
      var itemid = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
      var itemid_hash = "#" + itemid + " .details_exp";
      var itemid_tog_more = "#" + itemid + " a.more_info";       $(itemid_tog_more).addClass("less_info").removeClass("more_info");
      $(itemid_hash).fadeIn();
}, function () {
      var itemid = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
      var itemid_hash = "#" + itemid + " .details_exp";
      var itemid_tog_less = "#" + itemid + " a.less_info";
      $(itemid_tog_less).addClass("more_info").removeClass("less_info");
      $(itemid_hash).fadeOut();
});
```

First, is there a way to go up four levels in the DOM without stacking up .parent() four times? Second, is there a better way to define the "itemid" and " itemid_hash" variables so I don't have to redefine them for the second half of the toggle function? The code is working great as is, but I just want to make sure I've doing things in the most correct way. Thanks!

Comment: whats your html? using closest should be better then multpile parent calls.

Comment: If you show the corresponding HTML, it would be easier.

Comment: http://www.coryetzkorn.com/beta/ is the dev site address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2**: [**Working demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bExQE/)

**Update**: For completeness, this is the HTML I'm referring to (only relevant part):

```
<div class="work">
    <div class="details">
        <nav>
            <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
            <a href="#" class="more_info">more info</a>
            <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="details_exp" style="display: none; ">
            <!-- content here --->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

You can do like this:

```
$("a.more_info").toggle(function(){
      $(this).addClass("less_info").removeClass("more_info");
      // $(this).parent().nextAll('.details_exp').fadeIn() could work too
      $(this).closest('.work').find('.details_exp').fadeIn();
}, function () {
      $(this).addClass("more_info").removeClass("less_info");
      $(this).closest('.work').find('.details_exp').fadeOut();
});
```

There is no need to build the selectors manually. And I think `item_tog_less` actually refers to the currently clicked element right? Then you can just use `$(this)`.

If the box with the details always comes after the link (more precisely its parent, it looked like this) you can also do:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('.details_exp').fadeIn();
```

Reference: [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)

p.s.: Nice site!

Comment: yep, item_tog_less refers to the currently clicked element. I have a bunch of divs with the ".product" class four levels up from the "a.more_info" selector.

Comment: Brilliant! You just did in four lines what took me ten. I knew there had to be a better way. I always forget about .closest() and .find(), but they're obviously more essential than I thought. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In the case or the multiple parents you can change it for `closest`:

```
var itemid = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
```

For

```
var itemid = $(this).closest('#YourId or .YourClass');
```

The you can use selectors in a little part of the DOM instead of the whole DOM.

```
var itemid_hash = $(".details_exp", itemid );
```

And that will leave you with a jQuery object to do this

```
itemid_hash.fadeIn();
```